# Javac not creating all the .class files

Tags: java, compilation, javac

When I run `javac main/Main.java` (in the cd of `src`), it creates most of the class files, but not all of them.
This is my file structure

```
src
│
├───entity (creates .class files)
│
└───main (creates .class files)
    │
    ├───object (does not create all .class files)
    │
    └───tile (creates .class files)
```

I have tried `javac -d ./classes/ main/Main.java` but this only creates one .class file, and I don't want to have to go though each file in the tree.

Comment: It should create all .class files that are referenced from `Main`, and all class files that are referenced from those files, and so forth. Is `Main` in `package main`? i.e. is your package structure the same as your directory structure?

Comment: @user207421 Yes, my package structure is the same as my directory structure.

Comment: Just found a sort of fix. I'm using Atom to edit my code, and when I create new files with it, they don't seem to register with the system. But if I edit the files in VSCode then save, the classes are properly generated. Not sure why this is, but it works I guess.

Comment: Maybe Atom doesn't change the last-modification date?